# Search specific text from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, ioexception

I have been learning and stack one problem. I try to make searching specific name and employee number from text file.
I tried to research the online around, but I did not find specifically much result.

How can I fix this "cannot find symbol" issue and work it properly? 
I get error which say,

> .\txtFileReader.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
>           while((line = filescan.readLine()) != null)
>                                 ^   symbol:   method readLine()   location: variable filescan of type Scanner 1 error

My code is,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class txtFileReader
{
    private String words;
    private Scanner typescan, filescan; 

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        filescan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EmpInfo.txt"));
        String line = "";
        words = typescan.nextLine();
        while((line = filescan.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.matches(words))
            {
                System.out.print(line);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Sorry, could not find it.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

I added "BufferedReader filescan" part instead of using "filescan"
Still when after compile receive another error of "NullPointerException"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at txtFileReader.run(txtFileReader.java:15)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

...

```
  Public void run() throws IOException
        {
        BufferedReader filescan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EmpInfo.txt"));
        String line = "";
        words = typescan.nextLine();
```

...

Update2:

It still shows NullPointerException issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at txtFileReader.run(txtFileReader.java:15)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I am not sure but I assume because of text file have issue to read, it gives NullPointerException?

Answer (score 3):

Change `filescan` to `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader filescan;
```

**Update:**

`NullPointerException` is thrown because `typescan` is not initialized.

```
String words = "Something";
Scanner typescan; // Not used
BufferedReader filescan;

filescan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EmpInfo.txt"));
String line = "";
//words = typescan.nextLine(); // NullPointerException otherwise
while((line = filescan.readLine()) != null) {
    //if(line.matches(words)) { // What is this?
    if(line.equals(words)) { 
        System.out.print(line);
        break;
    }
}
```